# where is aeabi_fmul being linked from?

Tags: c, arm, bare-metal

I've been running code on the ARM M0+ core and i see that the vast majority of my time is spent in floating point calculations. So I am experimenting with a custom floating point calculation function for use in very low power applications.

I've been using ARM GCC for bare metal compile on an M0+ (without a hard FPU). I see that floating point multiplication gets linked to __aeabi_fmul and then linked to generate the final ELF file.

My questions are as follows:

1. Where is __aeabi_fmul defined? Is it in a pre-compiled library that comes with GCC?
2. Is it possible to change this definition in some way? Maybe have a pre-compiled version of my_fp_mul instead and link to that instead of __aeabi_fmul?

I understand that the second part needs me to mess with the compiler. I've been looking into CLANG/LLVM to do this since general consensus seems to be that its easier to modify than GCC! I'm just trying to see if this is even something thats possible or im barking up the entirely wrong tree here.

thank you

Comment: Likely part of libgcc .

Comment: If you want to experiment with your own math, better write new functions instead of breaking the intrinsics.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi, yes thats exactly what Im trying to do. but implementing these in a program would be rather unwieldy. Since its just C, i cant even overload operators to use my custom functions. So I am trying to see if i can do in a simpler way from the function. Maybe something like #pramga use_my_float c = a*b to signal to the compiler to use my custom float instead of the pre-defined __aeabi_fmul.

Comment: If I remember correctly you can simply override the library implementation with your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of gcc, the gcc library, download the gcc sources and search for those functions and you will find them.  They are soft float routines and are hand tuned and you are unlikely to do a significantly better job, but knock yourself out.  Not sure why you would do any floating point on an MCU like that but thankfully the language and the tools allow you although it can consume a lot of flash and execution time.  (not doing any float variables but doing the floating point math yourself with fixed point is a possible compromise or just do fixed point).

If you use gcc to link then gcc knows where the libraries are and will pull them in automatically, if you use ld to link (using gcc just as a compiler not the caller of everything in the toolchain) then ld does not know where to find the libraries and you can simply add your own object on the command line, this is the simplest way.

You can take the as-is gnu source for a particular function and add it to your project then modify it or just completely replace it with your own function.

Naturally you can go into the compiler sources and rename things then re-build the compiler, not sure just how much work you want to do here, replacing the floating point routines without mistakes is already a large task, as mentioned in comments I would leave the compiler alone and just work with it (leave the names the same link with ld).

start.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
```

so.c

```
float notmain ( float a, float b )
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

memmap

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > rom
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as start.s -o start.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Xlinker -T -Xlinker memmap -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mthumb start.o so.c -o so.elf -lgcc
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf
```

it doesnt complain but makes a perfectly broken binary

```
20000048 <__addsf3>:
20000048:   e1b02080    lsls    r2, r0, #1
2000004c:   11b03081    lslsne  r3, r1, #1
20000050:   11320003    teqne   r2, r3
20000054:   11f0cc42    mvnsne  r12, r2, asr #24
20000058:   11f0cc43    mvnsne  r12, r3, asr #24
2000005c:   0a000047    beq 20000180 <__addsf3+0x138>
20000060:   e1a02c22    lsr r2, r2, #24
20000064:   e0723c23    rsbs    r3, r2, r3, lsr #24
20000068:   c0822003    addgt   r2, r2, r3
2000006c:   c0201001    eorgt   r1, r0, r1
20000070:   c0210000    eorgt   r0, r1, r0
```

those are arm instructions not thumb.  examining what the linker was passed.

```
0:[/opt/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld]
1:[-plugin]
2:[/opt/gnuarm/libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/liblto_plugin.so]
3:[-plugin-opt=/opt/gnuarm/libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/lto-wrapper]
4:[-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccSyISCJ.res]
5:[-X]
6:[-o]
7:[so.elf]
8:[-L/opt/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/thumb]
9:[-L/opt/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0]
10:[-L/opt/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib]
11:[-T]
12:[memmap]
13:[start.o]
14:[/tmp/ccrdRU2s.o]
15:[-lgcc]
```

the other approach

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -mthumb so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T memmap start.o so.o /opt/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.1.0/thumb/libgcc.a  -o so.elf
```

but this is still broken

```
20000038 <__addsf3>:
20000038:   e1b02080    lsls    r2, r0, #1
2000003c:   11b03081    lslsne  r3, r1, #1
20000040:   11320003    teqne   r2, r3
20000044:   11f0cc42    mvnsne  r12, r2, asr #24
20000048:   11f0cc43    mvnsne  r12, r3, asr #24
2000004c:   0a000047    beq 20000170 <__addsf3+0x138>
20000050:   e1a02c22    lsr r2, r2, #24
20000054:   e0723c23    rsbs    r3, r2, r3, lsr #24
```

I have not done the things I need to do to get the right library, have to run will re-edit this later...

But my proposed solution is:

```
.thumb_func
.globl __aeabi_fadd
__aeabi_fadd:
    bx lr
```

I added to start.s for demonstration purposes

```
arm-none-eabi-as start.s -o start.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T memmap start.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

20000000 <_start>:
20000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
20000004:   20000015    andcs   r0, r0, r5, lsl r0
20000008:   20000019    andcs   r0, r0, r9, lsl r0
2000000c:   20000019    andcs   r0, r0, r9, lsl r0
20000010:   20000019    andcs   r0, r0, r9, lsl r0

20000014 <reset>:
20000014:   f000 f802   bl  2000001c <notmain>

20000018 <hang>:
20000018:   e7fe        b.n 20000018 <hang>

2000001a <__aeabi_fadd>:
2000001a:   4770        bx  lr

2000001c <notmain>:
2000001c:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
2000001e:   f7ff fffc   bl  2000001a <__aeabi_fadd>
20000022:   bc10        pop {r4}
20000024:   bc02        pop {r1}
20000026:   4708        bx  r1
```

then fill in whatever you want, clearly this is not a real program, broke many rules, there are no numbers being passed in, etc...

But the compiler generated __aeabi_fadd and I supplied an __aeabi_fadd and it was happy.

What I have done in the past, is, since I build my own gnu toolchain anyway, go in and put a syntax error in the file of interest, do the build, then the long command line used to build that item is now on the screen when it fails, isolate the function of interest, use the long command line for gcc as a guide, tweak and tune as desired...Get there faster than trying to figure out all the defines on your own in the code.

Comment: no reason to assume those specific function names are used across compilers so clang is free to use their own, they may choose to use the gcc ones for various reasons, just understand that I dont think the language spec defines the names of soft float library functions if the target doesnt support hard float for those functions

Comment: Hi @old_timer, thanks a lot for that detailed answer!

Oh, im not trying to improve on the floating point! its just that i noticed that a lot of the code is in there for error/bounds checking. but since i know exactly what the range of all my values are I dont really need to do that many checks. So i wanted a version without those to speed things up!

I agree about float vs. fixed. The programs im using are written using float so a solution that would work with those would be ideal, but yes switching to fixed is also a possible solution.

Comment: (cont.) Sorry but i didnt get the point about ld. would you be able to elaborate on that a bit? If i look at the gcc codebase and take their implementation and change it, will i be able to use 'my implementation' without recompiling GCC? would i just put a function with the same name, compile it and link it in using 'ld'? 

I didnt quite get the part about printing out the argv[] items on the command line. sorry!

Comment: forget about it then it was just a demonstration of how gcc calls ld if gcc is used for linking.  But if you use ld directly to link you have to specify where to find these libraries be they yours or the gcc libraries, you have to specify either way.  So that is the easiest approach, use gcc to make objects gas to build the bootstrap then ld to link (arm-whatever-ld naturally).

Comment: sure so removing limit checks would help you yes if you already know you are safe...

Comment: So if i have a function with the same name (__aeabi_fmul in this case) and link with ld, then it will use my implementation instead? 
In that case is there any way of changing what name a floating point multiply gets resolved to? could it be something other than __aeabi_fmul?

Comment: I just added a bogus program to demonstrate the parts and the dependencies  all you have to have is a function with the right name for the linker to find...use the linker not gcc (when you use gcc use it with a -c for compile to object then the linker to link the objects, the bootstrap needs to be first of the objects on the command line unless you have it called out by name in your linker script)

Comment: Actually according to the ARM C Runtime specification these helper function names are defined in the ARM EABI spec, for compiler interoperability purposes (hence the __aeabi prefix).

Comment: @TonyK that is fine, doesnt mean that is the case for all targets and all compilers.  I was speaking generically...the eabi part of the name does make it pretty obvious where the name came from or what it is associated with in this case for this target...I have not messed with other targets and fixed or float math (arm cores without a divide also use libgcc for fixed point) with gcc to see what naming convention they use...

Comment: Presumably if you use an ARM EABI compliant compiler then you are guaranteed these function names, but yeah they certainly don't need to be defined as part of a C library.

Comment: @TonyK true one would expect that, but I wouldnt expect MIPS or x86 or sparc or risc-v, msp430, avr, etc to use arms names for these C library functions.  So in general dont expect a specific name for a library function from each and every compiler, just figure it out, if they are the same and have the same prototype, great, makes life easier...

Comment: Right no argument there, it's just in OP's case ARM has conveniently defined these functions to allow easy overrides with custom implementations. I've seen this used on NXP micro controllers for example to call optimized ROM division codes.

Comment: No argument there either...the OP will find the well used names for this target.